# What is the best-practice to assign allocated objects to retain properties?

Tags: ios, memory-management, properties, coding-style

Dear fellow iOS developers,

I'm still developing without ARC (switching coming soon) and after an interesting discussion with a iOS beginner, I've presented my way to initialize a retain property (let's call it `property`), that I inherited from Apple docs at their pre-ARC era:

```
NSObject *tmpProperty = [[NSObject alloc] init];
self.property = tmpProperty;
[tmpProperty release];
```

I see a great benefit with this: it makes memory management clear.

There's also a great drawback: it takes 3 lines, for something very basic. So we assumed: why not the following solution?

```
self.property = [[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease];
```

It's less clear about memory management but much more compact (and it propably make the ARC-migration easier to achieve).

What are (were?) you using yourself? Do you think one of these is a clearly better solution than the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using autorelease is never a great option, as you have no control over the lifetime of the object you are initializing, so it may be the case that

In a ViewController you have initialized some object e.g. property, and you are swtiching to some other views, and if you want to come back to the older ViewController and access the object, it might be released by the iOS, and your app might crash.

I think **switching to ARC at the earliest** would be your best option. I think ARC should be used by every developer, almost all the devices are being provided by the iOS5 update, so there might be least chances of supporting older devices.

Hope this solves your doubt

Comment: memory management in objc is deterministic if you do it correctly. using autorelease will not change this

Comment: you can check out [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-1000922) for the usage of memory using autorelease.

Comment: i can't see anywhere mentioned autorelease should be avoided

Answer (score 0):

I am using the first where ever I can, because it uses less memory. In the second case the object you have allocated is released when the run loop finishes. This can be important when you have this code in a for loop or in a table view cell. In some circumstances this can make the difference between 'memory warning' and 'everything is fine'.

By the way: Switch to ARC.

Answer (score 0):

A little of *both*. I don't think it something that a convention should say "One or the other".

The one-liner works well when you need just one line. Ownership requires no additional reading.

When you need further initialization (e.g. before you set `self.property`) or in some cases want to minimize possibility of an object being added to an autorelease pool or its destruction more predictable, then you may favor the second.

However, I wouldn't fret about it much if you're about to move over to ARC -- a lot will change then and you may wind up going through extra work for no gain following the migration.